# PHP - print_r em xml está trazendo nome da Classe

Tags: php, xml, web-service

Tenho uma classe chamada `Cliente.php` que faz a conexão com o web service e tenho outra chamada `Requisição.php` que gerar o XML requisição e envia para a `Cliente.php`.

O problema é que a resposta que recebo do web service só consigo mostrar com `print_r` na classe `Cliente.php` e não consigo mostrar na classe `Requisição.php`, mesmo colocando `Cliente` com `return`.

O QUE MOSTRA É O NOME É: Cliente Object ( )

```
class Cliente {

    public function __construct($requisicao) {
        //Endereço e conexão com  o web service
        $client = new SoapClient("http://192.168.1.104:8082/wsdl/FChamada");
        //Requisição ao web service 
        $obj = $client->Requisicao($requisicao);
        //Retorno(Resposta) do web service
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($obj);
        //Retorna o a resposta do web service
        return $xml;  
    }
}



class Requisicao {

    /***********************************************************************
     ********************* REQUISÃO ****************************************
     **********************************************************************/
    public function query() {

        $req = new Requisicao_XML();
        //Gerando o xml requisição
        $requisicao = $req->toXML();

        //Envia o xml requisição para a classe Cliente e recebe o xml resposta
        $xml = new Cliente($requisicao);
        //Deveria mostrar o xml resposta
        print_r($xml)
    }

}
```

Comment: Por que o return no método construtor?

Comment: Já coloquei em outro método, e acontece a mesma coisa.

Comment: Está um tanto confuso para mim o que você quer fazer e o porque dessa organização de classes...

Comment: Ei cara foi mal, o erro foi meu, tirei do construtor  e realmente deu certo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No método `__contruct` não existe retorno, pois o retorno é o objeto. O que você pode fazer nesse caso é criar um método.

```
class Cliente {

    public static function Get($requisicao) {
        //Endereço e conexão com  o web service
        $client = new SoapClient("http://192.168.1.104:8082/wsdl/FChamada");
        //Requisição ao web service 
        $obj = $client->Requisicao($requisicao);
        //Retorno(Resposta) do web service
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($obj);
        //Retorna o a resposta do web service
        return $xml;  
    }
}



class Requisicao {

    /***********************************************************************
     ********************* REQUISÃO ****************************************
     **********************************************************************/
    public function query() {

        $req = new Requisicao_XML();
        //Gerando o xml requisição
        $requisicao = $req->toXML();

        //Envia o xml requisição para a classe Cliente e recebe o xml resposta
        $xml = Cliente::Get($requisicao);
        //Mostrar o xml resposta
        print_r($xml)
    }

}
```

Comment: Obrigado. Foi isso mesmo que fiz e deu certo.